# Identify okta account on sign-in

Tags: okta, kentor-authservices

I have an MVC application (.Net Framework 4.5) which is been there for the last three years and using Forms Authentication mechanism. This application provides different accounts like Personal, freebie, Enterprise etc. For an enterprise account, we are handling everything in the same application. I.e. Suppose an enterprise called “xyz” created an enterprise account with the application, then we are providing a custom url like “https://application/xyz/login” and from the url we are identifying that enterprise. I don’t know the exact reason why they implemented like this as I have seen applications that’s having enterprise accounts are created as sub domains (e.g. https://xyz.okta.com). 
Since the application is live I couldn’t modify the existing system. Now I want to integrate Okta into it. With the help of this blog post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43980281/programatically-configure-sso-settings-using-kentor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43980281/programatically-configure-sso-settings-using-kentor/) I was able to configure the settings from code.  I’m planning to store all configuration related things(Single sign-on URL, Audience URI etc) in the database. 
In an identity provider instantiated flow is there any way I can identify that the call is from which okta enterprise account?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Okta but perhaps you could inspect the claims that you receive and see if one of them has information about the enterprise?

Comment: I set the "Identity Provider Issuer" value (and I think which should be unique) to the Default RelayState field under General SAML settings tab and I was able to retrieve it from AuthServices\Acs action methods. Does it seem to be a good idea?

Comment: RelayState is not protected by signature like a normal assertion, so you may have to think about the impact if someone sends you fake or malicious values. But otherwise I think you can do whatever you want in that field, subject to the 80-character limitation.